# Measure width of numbers in Bitmaps

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, character

I created a texture (bitmap) that is used for drawing arbitrary numbers

The texture contains the text: 0123456789.-

[image: Actual Image]

Now I need the coordinates of each character.

`TextRenderer.MeasureText(c.ToString(), m_font, new Size(1, 1), TextFormatFlags.NoPadding);`

...returns is 16x17

`g.MeasureString(c.ToString(), m_font);`

...returns is 11.9x17.7

**The actual size is 8x11**

My workaround for now is a manual measurement of each character which yields the following table:

`coords.Add('0', new RectangleF(1, 3, 8, 11));
coords.Add('1', new RectangleF(9, 3, 7, 11));
coords.Add('2', new RectangleF(15, 3, 8, 11));
coords.Add('3', new RectangleF(22, 3, 8, 11));
coords.Add('4', new RectangleF(29, 3, 8, 11));
coords.Add('5', new RectangleF(36, 3, 8, 11));
coords.Add('6', new RectangleF(43, 3, 8, 11));
coords.Add('7', new RectangleF(50, 3, 8, 11));
coords.Add('8', new RectangleF(57, 3, 8, 11));
coords.Add('9', new RectangleF(64, 3, 8, 11));
coords.Add('.', new RectangleF(72, 3, 3, 11));
coords.Add('-', new RectangleF(75, 3, 6, 11));`

I would like to use a dynamic font, so a programmatic way to measure the size is required.

Comment: i think you'll have to look for more overloads of this. imagine you're trying to measure an i. how would you know the dot is part of the i instead of beeing a seperate character. Maybe you're getting unexpected values because it includes line height as well when calling the function.

Answer (score 1):

Tell the MeasureString method to work with the generic typographic StringFormat.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var image = new Bitmap(1000, 500);

            var g = Graphics.FromImage(image);
            g.FillRectangle(System.Drawing.Brushes.White, 0, 0, 1000, 500);

            var stringFormat = new StringFormat(StringFormat.GenericTypographic) {
                 Alignment = StringAlignment.Near,
                 FormatFlags = System.Drawing.StringFormatFlags.LineLimit | System.Drawing.StringFormatFlags.NoClip | StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft
            };

            var font = new Font(new System.Drawing.FontFamily("Times New Roman"), 72.0f,FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Point);
            var point = new PointF { X = 10, Y = 10 };

            SizeF[] outputs = new SizeF[7];
            SizeF[] total = new SizeF[7];
            outputs[0] = g.MeasureString("T", font, point, stringFormat);
            outputs[1] = g.MeasureString("e", font, point, stringFormat);
            outputs[2] = g.MeasureString("s", font, point, stringFormat);
            outputs[3] = g.MeasureString("t", font, point, stringFormat);
            outputs[4] = g.MeasureString("S", font, point, stringFormat);
            outputs[5] = g.MeasureString("t", font, point, stringFormat);
            outputs[6] = g.MeasureString("r", font, point, stringFormat);

            total[0] = g.MeasureString("T", font, point, stringFormat);
            total[1] = g.MeasureString("Te", font, point, stringFormat);
            total[2] = g.MeasureString("Tes", font, point, stringFormat);
            total[3] = g.MeasureString("Test", font, point, stringFormat);
            total[4] = g.MeasureString("TestS", font, point, stringFormat);
            total[5] = g.MeasureString("TestSt", font, point, stringFormat);
            total[6] = g.MeasureString("TestStr", font, point, stringFormat);

            stringFormat.FormatFlags = System.Drawing.StringFormatFlags.LineLimit | System.Drawing.StringFormatFlags.NoClip;

            g.DrawString("TestStr", font, System.Drawing.Brushes.Red, new PointF { X = 10, Y = 10 }, stringFormat);
            g.DrawRectangle(new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Brushes.Blue, 1.0f), GetOutputPositionX(total,outputs, 0), 10.0f, outputs[0].Width, outputs[0].Height);
            g.DrawRectangle(new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Brushes.Blue, 1.0f), GetOutputPositionX(total,outputs, 1), 10.0f, outputs[1].Width, outputs[1].Height);
            g.DrawRectangle(new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Brushes.Blue, 1.0f), GetOutputPositionX(total,outputs, 2), 10.0f, outputs[2].Width, outputs[2].Height);
            g.DrawRectangle(new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Brushes.Blue, 1.0f), GetOutputPositionX(total,outputs, 3), 10.0f, outputs[3].Width, outputs[3].Height);
            g.DrawRectangle(new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Brushes.Blue, 1.0f), GetOutputPositionX(total,outputs, 4), 10.0f, outputs[4].Width, outputs[4].Height);
            g.DrawRectangle(new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Brushes.Blue, 1.0f), GetOutputPositionX(total,outputs, 5), 10.0f, outputs[5].Width, outputs[5].Height);
            g.DrawRectangle(new System.Drawing.Pen(System.Drawing.Brushes.Blue, 1.0f), GetOutputPositionX(total,outputs, 6), 10.0f, outputs[6].Width, outputs[6].Height);

            image.Save(@"c:\Temp\bla.png");

        }
        private static float GetOutputPositionX(SizeF[] total, SizeF[] outputs, int p)
        {
            return 10.0f + total[p].Width - outputs[p].Width;
        }
```

To get the Position exactly, because of these overlapping characters you have to calculate the width of "e" and the total width of "Te".

Plus there is obviously a bug in the MeasureString function. If you call MeasureString without the StringFormatFlags.DirectionRightToLeft the overlap of the characters "Te" is ignored.

[image]

Comment: I can't get this to work. I took the exact code and put it into a new solution, but the alignment of the green grid is wrong in my case. Can you please check again?

Comment: @testalino Could you add your output image.

Comment: @testalino I've tested in a WPF application before and it worked fine. In the console application GDI overlaps the characters "Te". Which for any reason doesn't happen within a WPF application. I've updated my code. Should work now.

Comment: OK thank you very much for the work you put into this. I can get the same result as you posted when using your code. Although it still doesn't work in my environment, because when you lower the font size, the frame suddenly does not fit the letters anymore, maybe because of rounding to the pixels. This is especially the case when using my actual font (Tahoma, 10): http://i.imgur.com/egBQLn6.png